# Google Earth regions not working

Tags: angularjs, directive, google-earth-plugin

The following code is in an angular directive:

```
      // -- Regions stuff
      var regions = {};
      regions.us = {};
      var lod = ge.createLod('');
      var ne = {n:37.3214096102,s:26.9898707181,e:-90.4503326416,w:-107.730612278};
      lod.set(128, -1, 0, 0);

      //107.730612278,26.9898707181 -90.4503326416,26.9898707181 -90.4503326416,37.3214096102 -107.730612278,37.3214096102
      var usNe = ge.createLatLonAltBox('');
      usNe.setAltBox(
        ne.n, // north
        ne.s, // south
        ne.e, // east
        ne.w, // west
        0, // rotation
        0, // min altitude
        0, // max altitude
        ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND // mode
        );

      regions.us.ne = ge.createRegion('');
      regions.us.ne.set(usNe, lod); // lat lon alt box, level of detail
      // --

      var icon = ge.createIcon('');
      var offIcon = ge.createIcon('');
      var style = ge.createStyle('');
      var offStyle = ge.createStyle('');

      icon.setHref(window.location.href + '/assets/images/lightbulb.png');
      offIcon.setHref(window.location.href + '/assets/images/lightbulb_off.png');
      style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon);
      offStyle.getIconStyle().setIcon(offIcon);
      style.getIconStyle().setScale(1);
      offStyle.getIconStyle().setScale(1);
      icon.setViewRefreshMode(ge.VIEW_REFRESH_ON_REGION);
      offIcon.setViewRefreshMode(ge.VIEW_REFRESH_ON_REGION);
      icon.setW(16);
      icon.setH(16);
      offIcon.setW(16);
      offIcon.setH(16);

      scope.control.createPlacemark = function (lat, lng, sale, to) {
        to = to || 0;
        var placemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
        var point = ge.createPoint('');
        point.setLatitude(+lat);
        point.setLongitude(+lng);
        placemark.setGeometry(point);
        placemark.setStyleSelector(style);
        ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);

        if (+lng <= ne.e && +lng >= ne.w && +lat >= ne.s && +lat <= ne.n) {
          placemark.setRegion(regions.us.ne);
          console.log('done!');
        }

        $timeout(function () {
          placemark.setStyleSelector(offStyle);
        }, to);
        return placemark;
      };
```

When `scope.control.createPlacemark` is called, it is creating the placemarks, and the ones within the regions have their regions being set, but nothing is happening in terms of zoom level / visibility. I would expect that the ones within the bounds would appear at different altitudes then other placemarks, but they're appearing at the same time. Any ideas as to what might be causing this behavior? It seems as though regions aren't working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, creating folders to associate with my regions solved my problem. I had so many placemarks that it had become difficult to tell which one was getting associated with the region, and the above code was only associating one of the placemarks (not sure if that is intended behavior).

Resulting code looks like

```
var folder = ge.createFolder('');
folder.setRegion(region);
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(folder);

// Then later in the placemark creation method
folder.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
```